# django - get all objects with True value in one queryset

Tags: python, django

For ForeignKeys i can do select_related(), but is there any way to do something similar to BooleanFields? My app is currently checking over 600 times if an object has is_app_category set to True, which is an overkill and takes over 10 seconds to load the page (still a small number as the final product will have thousands of entries)

views.py:

```
def assign_app_categories(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_admin:
        category_list = Categories.objects.select_related('company').filter(show_in_menu = True, is_app_category = False)
    else:
        category_list = Categories.objects.filter(company = user.company, show_in_menu = True)
    number_of_categories = len(category_list)
    zipped_data = {}
    CategoriesFormSet = formset_factory(CategoriesAssignForm, extra = number_of_categories)
    if request.method == "POST":
        categoriesFormSet = CategoriesFormSet(request.POST)
        if categoriesFormSet.is_valid():
            for (name, cleaned_form) in zip(category_list, categoriesFormSet.cleaned_data):
                if cleaned_form.get('parent') != None:
                    if user.is_admin:
                        category_item = Categories.objects.filter(name = name).filter(show_in_menu = True)[0]
                    else:
                        category_item = Categories.objects.get(company = user.company, name = name)
                    category_item.parent = cleaned_form.get('parent')
                    category_item.show_in_menu = False
                    category_item.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Categories are assigned to App categories!'))
            history = HistoryLog(user = request.user, function = 'categories.assign_app_categories', kind = 404 ).save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/categories/')
    else:
        categoriesFormSet = CategoriesFormSet()
        zipped_data = zip(category_list, categoriesFormSet)
    return render(request, 'categories/assign.html', {'zipped_data': zipped_data, 'category_list': category_list, 'categoriesFormSet': categoriesFormSet, 'menu':'categories'})
```

django-debug-toolbar:

```
SELECT "categories_categories"."id",
"categories_categories"."is_app_category",
"categories_categories"."brand_id",
"categories_categories"."company_id",
"categories_categories"."name",
"categories_categories"."slug",
"categories_categories"."description",
"categories_categories"."show_in_menu",
"categories_categories"."gender",
"categories_categories"."parent_id",
"categories_categories"."products_count", 
"categories_categories"."date_create",
"categories_categories"."date_modified"
FROM "categories_categories" WHERE "categories_categories"."is_app_category" = 'True'

Duplicated 633 times.
```

Comment: Do you really need the `Q` queries? wouldn't `filter(show_in_menu=True, is_app_category=False)` do the same thing?

Comment: Yes it does. This project has been handed to me from a person that doesn't work here anymore and my job is to fix it and make it run smooth. Kind of hard thing to do as most of the things don't work as they are supposed to.

Comment: Does my suggestion solve the issue though? It may make the query slightly quicker but as for any performance enhancements... what values do you actually need out of the category? how is it being used?

Comment: That would indicate to me that the problem isn't with the query then, just how it is being used

Comment: It gives the same results, but with no performance improvements.

I make imports of products from different brands in xml files. Each of the brands might have different names of categories of their products, so the view gets all products for me (is_app_category set to False on default) to assign the correct categories used by my site (which will then set is_app_category to True).

Comment: It would help to see where you call this query 633 times, what code causes it to loop?

Answer (score 0):

Now whilst I can't say for certain that these below will help, they certainly won't hurt

1. Dont use len to figure out how many categories, this forces the resolution of the queryset unnecessarily, instead use `.count()`
2. Your entire `user.is_admin` if else seems strange to me since you're just filtering categories again based off a previously found category, and since checking against `name` will just do a pk comparison, you're not going to be filtering out anything extra so `category_item` is already the equivalent to `name` before doing any of this filtering at all.
3. Having said all of that, you don't actually care if the `category_item` is returned, so you could just use [`.update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#update) on a queryset to update those matching results on the database side

Aside from this, you need to look at what you actually need out of the category_list, you should try to make use of [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values) or `values_list` to only return fields you care about.

Comment: Most of the times I don't even enter the
    if request.method == "POST"

so the issue is elsewhere

Comment: @JarosławSamulewski - Then see my amendment, you should look into using `values`